# Vim editor creating a copy of current file when i use :w! command to write the file

Tags: vim

I am using Vim Editor in windows. Its VIM 8.0

When i try to edit and save a file, am seeing a copy of a file creating in my directory. How to make sure not to create a copy.

Am using :w! to save the file.

Comment: see `:help backup-table`

Comment: Did you tried saving like `:w! Currentfilename`? Just add the current file name after w command. Try this and tell me.